# Trying to match this regular expression: PHP

Tags: php, regex

EDIT: I am trying to match the **year** in the string below

```
   $expression = "BORN ON:</th><td>weekday, Month Day, Year 
hr:min:sec AM timezone</td>"
```

`AM` maybe `pm`, `timezone` could be `pst` etc year is always 20-something

I've tried:

```
$pattern = "~BORN ON:</th><td>\w+(/20\d\d/)\w+</td>~";
```

to no avail, help is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Could you give a few examples of what `$expression` might look like? Your format looks so different from your regular expression that I think one of them must be quite wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you should backslash "`/`" symbols. and make sure you have leading and trailing slash in your expression e.g.

```
$pattern = "~BORN ON:<\/th><td>\w+(\/20\d\d/)\w+<\/td>~";

preg_match("/...../", $where, $results);
```

secondly, here is updated expression:

```
preg_match("/BORN ON:<\/th><td>\w, \w [0-9]+, [0-9]+ [0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+ (AM|PM) \w <\/td>/i", $where, $results);
```

not tested, but should match your needs. also, enclose parts that you need to appear in results - atm, all date would be found in $results[1] if matched.

---

upd

```
preg_match("/BORN ON:<\/th><td>(\w, \w [0-9]+, ([0-9]+) [0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+ (AM|PM) \w) <\/td>/i", $where, $results);
```

$results[1] now would contain year

Answer (score 0):

Try to get this string separately :

```
$string_time = "weekday, Month Day, Year hr:min:sec AM timezone" ;
// you use str_replace to get it
```

then use php builtin function :

```
$the_time = strtotime($string_time);
```

now you can manipulate it anyway you want, if that's what you are looking for.

You can use `date("...",$string_time)` to get it in any format you want.
ex:

```
echo date("Y-m-d",$string_time);
```

Comment: @algorithmicCoder you can still use this method to get the year

Answer (score 0):

I matched using this in Ruby.  Regex is prolly same in PHP.  Try it out.  Let me know if you have any issues.  I would love to help.  Good luck! :)

```
string = "BORN ON:</th><td>weekday, Month Day, Year hr:min:sec AM timezone</td>"
regex = /<\/th><td>([^,]+)\s*,\s*([^ ]+)\s+([^,]+)\s*,\s*([^ ]+)\s+([^:]+):([^:]+):([^ ]+)\s+(AM|PM)([^<]+)<\/td>/i
if regex.match(string)
    puts "match"
    puts "#{$1} is weekday"
    puts "#{$2} is month"
    puts "#{$3} is day"
    puts "#{$4} is year"
    puts "#{$5} is hour"
    puts "#{$6} is minutes"
    puts "#{$7} is seconds"
    puts "#{$8} is Am or Pm"
    puts "#{$9} is timezone"
else
    puts "no match"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work:

```
"~BORN ON:</th><td>\w+, \w+ [0-9]+, ([0-9]+)~";
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this to extract the year?

```
$strs = array( 
    "BORN ON:</th><td>weekday, Month 05, 2011 hr:min:sec AM timezone</td>",
    "BORN ON:</th><td>Sunday, Jan 05, 2010 hr:min:sec AM timezone</td>",
    "BORN ON:</th><td>Tuesday, 11 05, 2019 hr:min:sec AM timezone</td>"    
);

foreach( $strs as $subject)
    if( preg_match('%BORN ON:</th><td>\w+,\s*\w+\s*\w+,\s*(\d+)\s*%im', $subject, $regs))
        echo $regs[1] . "\n";
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/pn5rCf)